# Angular-service TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveURL' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

I am trying to write a service to store query string of a URL. I am doing so by storing it in a cookie and then retrieving it. But when i try to access the saveURL method from the controller to add the query string, I am getting this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveURL' of undefined

controller.js

```
angular
    .module("app.alerts.alertView")
    .controller("AlertViewsController", AlertViewsController);

    AlertViewsController.$inject = [
        "$scope", "$location", "alertHistory"
    ];

    function AlertViewsController($scope, $location, alertHistory) {
        alertHistory.saveURL($location.search());
    }
```

service.js

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("app.alerts.alertView")
        .service("alertHistory", alertHistory);

    alertHistory.$inject = [
        "$cookieStore"];

    function alertHistory ($cookieStore) {
        return {
            saveURL: function (urlObj) {
                var array = $cookieStore.get("key");
                array.push(urlObj);
                $cookieStore.put("key", array);
            }
        };
    }
})();
```

I have injected the service correctly. What else can i correct to solve the error. Please help

Comment: Are you sure that the service file is loading in the browser, and in the right order (angular first, then services etc.)

Comment: Yes, loading occurs in right sequence.

Comment: the sequence is angular, service, controller! is that correct ?

Comment: you should be able to load your controller before your service and vice versa.  Your code works without any issues on my end.  You should post a plunkr or give us a more complete example.

Answer (score 0):

What it looks like is happening is that you are not returning what you think you are returning because the return object is not concrete enough for JS to hang on to.  Also, you forgot to inject the `$location` service.  I would try rewriting it as follows:

```
angular
    .module("app.alerts.alertView")
    .service("alertHistory", [ '$cookieStore', function ($cookieStore) {
    var x = {};
    x.saveURL = function (urlObj) {
        var array = $cookieStore.get("key");
        array.push(urlObj);
        $cookieStore.put("key", array);
    };
    return x;
}]).controller('AlertViewsController', [ '$scope', '$location', 'alertHistory', function ($scope, $location, alertHistory) {
    alertHistory.saveURL($location.search());
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I tried adding empty variable. but it didnt work :( I had injected $location in my code. only missed out here.